# ARGH udev won't stop renaming my interfaces!

Tags: boot, networking, udev

I have the following in `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

```
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="d0:50:99:50:43:17", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="d0:50:99:50:43:18", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="68:05:ca:1a:ce:9d", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth2"
```

However, on boot, `udev` hate me. Why?

`dmesg` snips:

```
[   13.328778] e1000e 0000:01:00.0 eth0: registered PHC clock
[   13.328781] e1000e 0000:01:00.0 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 68:05:ca:1a:ce:9d
[   13.328783] e1000e 0000:01:00.0 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[   13.970303] igb 0000:07:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[   13.970305] igb 0000:07:00.0: eth1: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) d0:50:99:50:43:17
[   13.970434] igb 0000:07:00.0: eth1: PBA No: 001300-000
[   14.013474] igb 0000:08:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[   14.013476] igb 0000:08:00.0: eth2: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) d0:50:99:50:43:18
[   14.013603] igb 0000:08:00.0: eth2: PBA No: 001300-000
[   16.274874] systemd-udevd[155]: renamed network interface eth2 to p121p1
[   16.847244] systemd-udevd[160]: renamed network interface eth1 to p119p1
[   19.425858] systemd-udevd[607]: renamed network interface eth0 to eth2
```

How come the third works but the first two don't?

Comment: It appears to be a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/biosdevname/+bug/1284043

Comment: Just saw the notes here: https://wiki.debian.org/Bonding about UDEV. I'm going to try and rename by PCI address and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope that didn't work either...

Comment: Actually I did get it to work eventually with PCI address ID. You have to put this in `etc/default/grub`: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="ipv6.disable=1 net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I did get it to work eventually with PCI address ID. Two things, you have to:

1. Put/edit this in `etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=1 biosdevname=0
   ```

   then do a `sudo update-grub`
2. Put your desired names into `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`, like this:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", KERNELS=="0000:03:00.0", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
   ```

   Where `0000:03:00.0` is your PCI address you located in your `dmesg` output.

**Note:** No need to disable IPV6, I forgot that flag was in there. We just don't use it, so we disable it for safety.

Answer (score 3):

1. Append this to /etc/default/grub:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
   ```
2. Update bootloader :

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Reboot!

   ```
   reboot
   ```

Tested on ubuntu 15.10

Comment: the OP already posted the answer in a comment... also, an accepted answer is already here.

Comment: you wrong I did it and if you don't set  `net.ifnames=0` kernel will rename the interfaces. I don't really know maybe on other version it differ.