# Stop ethernet an wlan interfaces being renamed

Tags: networking, grub2

On Ubuntu 16.04.01 i'm trying to build a generic image I can use across multiple devices however i've found network adaptors are being renamed making it hard for /etc/network/interfaces configuration.

dmesg

```
[    6.473525] rtl8192cu 2-1.3:1.0 wlx801f02d2f4b1: renamed from wlan0
```

I tried changing

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
```

in /etc/default/grub and doing update-grub but it still gets renamed, I would like interfaces to be names eth0 eth1 wlan0 wlan0 etc.

I don't appear to have any persistent rules

```
sudo cat /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules
cat: /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590029/argh-udev-wont-stop-renaming-my-interfaces?rq=1

Comment: Yes as stated i've already tried that fix but it's not working.

Comment: Check the related link in my comment.

Comment: Yes as stated i've already tried that fix but it's not working

Comment: I see 2 answers. It appears that you tried the first but not the 2nd. If you did, please [edit] that information into your question to avoid further confusion, helping us help you in the process.